# UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, solr, amazon-eks, solrcloud

I have a SolrCloud cluster that runs on AWS EKS, I have configured the Solr.xml so that I can backup my Collections on a Repository on AWS S3 like follwoing:

```
<backup>
   <repository name="S3" class="org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.HdfsBackupRepository" default="true">
      <str name="location">s3://......</str>
      <str name="solr.hdfs.home">s3://.....</str>
   </repository>
</backup>
```

now, when I run the following curl inside the container on the EC2

```
curl -i 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=BackupName&collection=collectionName&repository=S3'
```

I got then

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":6},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException"],
    "msg":"org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme \"s3\"",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme \"s3\"\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.HdfsBackupRepository.init(HdfsBackupRepository.java:102)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.BackupRepositoryFactory.newInstance(BackupRepositoryFactory.java:75)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.newBackupRepository(CoreContainer.java:281)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.lambda$static$33(CollectionsHandler.java:1106)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.execute(CollectionsHandler.java:1338)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:276)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:248)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:216)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:836)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:800)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:545)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:427)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:357)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:177)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:322)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme \"s3\"\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3281)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3301)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:476)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.HdfsBackupRepository.init(HdfsBackupRepository.java:100)\n\t... 50 more\n",
    "code":500}}
```

Note:
I have added the S3FullAccess Permission to the NodeGroupRole.

Comment: The error message says that there is no support for the `s3://` filesystem scheme in your Hadoop version. `s3://` was removed in Hadoop 3. Try to use `s3a://` (preferred) or `s3n://` instead (`s3n` is also removed in the most recent versions of Hadoop).

Comment: See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html for more information about the `s3a://` scheme.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh, that helps me going further, but now, I'm getting `ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found`

Comment: You need to have the `hadoop-aws` jar available in your classpath (see https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/libs.html for how to add library directories to Solr)

Comment: Hallo @MatsLindh, Thank you again for your Replys, I did that and added the Jars `aws-java-sdk-1.11.1021.jar and hadoop-aws-3.3.0.jar` to the $SOLR_HOME/lib and also configured the SharedLib in solr.xml like `<str name="sharedLib">$SOLR_HOME/lib</str>` but still not working, I need to check again, if I forget something. But your comments helped me anyway.